# Remove ":80" from a URL via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, phpbb, phpbb3

I need to strip **:80** out of URLs when it is part of a URL using HTTPS.

An example URL:

https://www.domain.com:80

In .htaccess I have tried:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.domain.com:80 [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://domain.com [L,R=302]
</IfModule>
```

I have also tried:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>    
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What is adding the port to the URL to begin with?

Comment: I'm running an old phpBB forum (3.0.1) for a client that can't immediately upgrade to the latest version because of all the extensions that are built on it. The long-term solution is obviously to upgrade or fix the bug within the forum software but until then I'm hoping to use htaccess so the SSL certificate will work.

Comment: Also, it's only being added during redirects (i.e. when someone signs in or posts a response to a post).

Comment: Actually I forgot to ask before providing the answer what happens when you go to that URL, do you have a valid cert also?

Comment: Yeah, the cert is definitely valid. There are no issues accessing any normal https URL but obviously putting a port 80 in the URL will mess it up.

Comment: Ok, I add a foot note to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Ok well you should be able to check if https is on and if the port is 80 then redirect. Use a combination of conditions. See if this works for you.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

Note this solution `should` work but may also have to enable ssl on port 80 in the vhost as well in the event it comes in that way.

Comment: No luck so far. I'll include it with my support ticket to my web host. I need to verify there's nothing at the server level limiting my use of htaccess.

Comment: Thanks for the help but my host says that htaccess is not going to work because "mod_rewrite affects incoming URLs (requests) not outgoing URLs (responses)."

Comment: What exactly is your host talking about? This is isn't client side. What outgoing URLs?